# How to implement SwipeRefreshLayout on a ListFragment with onActivityCreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, swiperefreshlayout

A have a ListFragment on my app that has an `onActivityCreated` method that runs  when the activity is created:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    readJson(); //populates the list
    featured = new ArrayList();
}
```

I want to implement a `SwipeRefreshLayout`, so I used the `SwipeRefreshListFragment`from the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshListFragment/src/com.example.android.swiperefreshlistfragment/SwipeRefreshListFragment.html). But, I noticed that in the Android Docs, their fragment used the `onCreate` and `onViewCreated` methods to implement this. But, since I am using the `onActivityCreated`, I am unable to mimic their setup. How would a go about using a `SwipeRefreshLayout` here? I tried to change my code from `onActivityCreated` to `onCreate`, but that doesn't work since I built the fragment with the `onActivityCreated` method.

Comment: More information need to investigate your issue. Please put your all code here. Also  readJson(); should be ran on a AsyncTask.

Comment: @RanjithSubramaniam the readJson(); is getting the data via the use of volley, so it's already running on AsyncTask by default

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that they do anything in `onCreate` of the fragment. "everything" is in `onCreateView` like you should expect. I have "inherited" old, bad code which does it like you want it. Only difference: the SwipeRefreshLayout is searched with `getActivity().findViewById(...)`. I don't know why they didn't save the reference to the view of the fragment in onCreateView() but I don't care because I moved the code there...

"I built the fragment with the onActivityCreated" doesn't make any sense to me. onActivityCreated() is a method of the fragment - so it is already built. You should construct your adapter in onCreateView() and then call your readJson() there.